# image map coordinates ms paint for windows 7

Tags: image, dictionary, coordinates, imagemap

help,

so frustrated.  Brand new so sorry about this question but i can't find the answer for the life of me.  I created an image map and have to find the x y coordinates for the clickable areas.  The only image editor i have is ms paint 7 and i cannot find the coordinates for the life of me.  When i scroll over the area it shows me the pixels but these are not the correct coordinates.  Does anyone know how to find them?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried searching everywhere for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using gimp

[Link for GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)

Its a free and powerful software for manipulating and creating images.
it should help you with finding coordinates .

Comment: Thanks you very much for your response.  i have since downloaded GIMP and it has solved my problem.  it is a very powerful tool and i had not come across it in my own research.